# Terraform on Windows using SSH to remote-exec

Tags: terraform

I am new to terraform, and have been trying to adapt a working script that my colleague created on Mac. I am using Git Bash and terraform v0.12.5. I am able to run terraform plan and apply, but when it attempts to remote-exec I get SSH errors. I started off using Open-SSH but saw that "On Windows the only supported SSH authentication agent is Pageant." So I setup Pageant and tested this with Github which worked. I now am struggling again with terraform. I have tried a variety of options but am not sure what is the correct format for the Provisioner Connection. Currently I am using this:

```
  connection {
    host = self.public_ip
    type = "ssh"
    user = "ubuntu"
    agent = "true"
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/aws.pem")}"
  }
```

```
Error: timeout - last error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

Any pointers would be great as I have tried, removing the private_key, modifying the file to a .ppk, also looked at specifying the agent_identity but not sure what to define for that value. Thanks.

Comment: Answered my own question..The public key was changed on AWS. So the private key I was using was no longer valid. I tested my private key by direct ssh to the instance that had been deployed and it failed. Proving it wasn't pageant, windows just the wrong key... I learnt to test the ssh earlier.

Comment: So which key finally worked? .pem or .ppk?

Comment: In the end I installed Windows Subsystem for Linux and used Terraform from there. A simpler option. I used a pem file with that connection.